# /proc/diskstats disk time spent writing more than 1000ms*CPU-core-count per second

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-kernel, io, proc

I'm interested in how could one interpret the results of procfs-diskstats. It looks like an API, but I see no exhaustive explanation in Internet or man pages or Linux kernel Documentation.

There is a [file](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/ABI/testing/procfs-diskstats) with a very concise description:

```
The /proc/diskstats file displays the I/O statistics
of block devices. Each line contains the following 14
fields:

        ==  ===================================
         1  major number
         2  minor mumber
         3  device name
         4  reads completed successfully
         5  reads merged
         6  sectors read
         7  time spent reading (ms)
         8  writes completed
         9  writes merged
        10  sectors written
        11  time spent writing (ms)
        12  I/Os currently in progress
        13  time spent doing I/Os (ms)
        14  weighted time spent doing I/Os (ms)
        ==  ===================================
        ...
```

And also [iostats.rst](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/admin-guide/iostats.rst) with a few words more. But it's still hard to tell what exactly means f.e. this metric:

```
13  time spent doing I/Os (ms)
```

From iostats.rst:

```
Field 10 -- # of milliseconds spent doing I/Os (unsigned int)
    This field increases so long as field 9 is nonzero.

    Since 5.0 this field counts jiffies when at least one request was
    started or completed. If request runs more than 2 jiffies then some
    I/O time might be not accounted in case of concurrent requests.
```

But when I watch this value **per second** on my 4-core CPU VM, this value growing(increments) by **more than 100000 ms** while copying f.e 4Gb file.
I can assume that **HDD/SSD**(SATA? Depends on bus?) **could serve multiple CPU cores requests in parallel**.
On 4-core CPU that means that 100000 ms increment in this counter represents HDD/SDD serving [at least 25 seconds on every CPU core's request] per second. Or 50 seconds on two cores (per second), or 100 second on 1 core (per second).

Common sense dictates that you cannot work more time per second than a second.

Related post: [/proc/diskstats disk read time increasing more than second per second](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/581778/proc-diskstats-disk-read-time-increasing-more-than-second-per-second/581790)

UPD: Linux kernel 4.4.161, x86_64

Comment: I didn't manage to reproduce it. When dd from the disk from 2 process (on a 2 core processor), I get a maximum of 1004ms / 1s and I guess that my 1s loop made with a sleep(1) system call is not precise enough. From the Linux 4.9 source, I have a comment idencating that a care has been done to avoid more than 100% time reported : "Normally, that accounting is done on IO completion, but that can result in more than a second's worth of IO being accounted for within any one second, leading to >100% utilisation.  To deal with that, [...]."

Comment: Could you please name the kernel version (4.19, 5.0, 5.10 etc) and the architecture (PC, ARM etc.)?

Comment: @Binarus Updated the question.

Comment: OK, thanks for the update. The kernel in the VM is quite old. You are right, the counter should not increase by more than 1000/sec. Guessing wildly, I'd say that the virtual disk driver *in the guest* has problems reporting those statistics correctly, or that the VM heavily suffers from a timing / lost interrupt problem. To analyze that, detailed knowledge would be required about how you have configured the VM and its virtual disk. It would be interesting what `/proc/diskstats` shows for the VM's virtual disk *on the host* (provided that it is not just a file).